# CSS Disabled scrolling

Tags: css, vertical-scrolling

I came across an issue with one of our web sites:

In IE9 the page had a vertical scrollbar, but you couldn't use the mousewheel, arrow keys, pgup/pgdwn to scroll.  The only way to scroll was to actually click/hold and move the scrollbar.

I removed the following from the css:

```
{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Then scrolling worked as usual.  Has anyone else come across this?  It seems odd as overflow-x should hide the horizontal scroll bar?  Why would it effect the vertical?

I have tried this on a test page and it acts as expected.  So it must be a combination of things.

Comment: `"*I have tried this on a test page and it acts as expected. So it must be a combination of things."` - unless someone has come across this before, we *need* a test page that reproduces the problem. You can either post a link to the site, or take a copy of the page yourself and anonymise it and have all the required CSS (and any JavaScript *relevant to the problem*) included and post it on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/).

Comment: Apologies, I don't have permission to post a link to the materials themselves (they are subscription only).  This was mainly out of interest, as I have managed to fix the issue, its just I don't understand why the fix worked. Unfortunately I can't simply upload a page as it is part of an e-learning system.

Answer (score 47):

Try using the following code snippet. This should solve your issue.

```css
body, html { 
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

`overflow-x: hidden;`
would hide any thing on the x-axis that goes outside of the element, so there would be no need for the horizontal scrollbar and it get removed.

`overflow-y: hidden;`
would hide any thing on the y-axis that goes outside of the element, so there would be no need for the vertical scrollbar and it get removed.

`overflow: hidden;`
would remove both scrollbars

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? overflow-y controls the vertical scrollbar: http://jsfiddle.net/ddVTk/

Answer (score 4):

I use iFrame to insert the content from another page and CSS mentioned above is NOT working as expected. I have to use the parameter scrolling="no" even if I use HTML 5 Doctype