# How to scroll the menu, without scrolling the content of the page in the background?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, navigation

On my site I have a menu on the right. When I scroll down the menu and I come down, the background page scrolls too.

I would like the page in the background does not scroll. How to do this ?

Here is a page of my site, click on the menu on the right:

https://www.s1biose.com/recette

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335444/css-disabled-scrolling may be helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Disabled scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335444/css-disabled-scrolling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable scrolling in many ways:

With CSS:

```
$('html, body').css({
    overflow: 'hidden',
    height: '100%'
});
```

This will disable scrolling and bring you to the top of the page.

Alternatively, you can use JavaScript (jQuery) to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".navbar-toggle-second[aria-expanded='false']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
  });

  $(".navbar-toggle-second[aria-expanded='true']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("body").css("overflow", "auto");
  });
});
```

For more information, see this:

[How to programmatically disable page scrolling with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656592/how-to-programmatically-disable-page-scrolling-with-jquery)

Comment: What I'm trying to do is block the scrolling of the content behind the collapse menu. When the menu is open.

Comment: The following code looks good
 https://forum.webflow.com/t/how-to-prevent-body-from-scrolling-when-modal-window-open/29959/3 in the case of my menu, what should I put in my JS file ?

Comment: I've edited the code so it should work for your case. Make sure to include jQuery

Comment: what I want to do is when the menu is open, the content behind should not scroll, should not be clickable and must be darkened.

Comment: I want the behavior to be modal

Comment: https://www.s1biose.com/profil/adeline on this page if you click on "Signaler un problème" under the profile, a modal window opens and the content behind gets darker, is not clickable and you can not scroll down. That's what I'm trying to do with the menu collapse.

Comment: When I open your example, it's working. Is the problem solved then?